# I Haven't Booted to Ubuntu yet. Once I do, how will I get back to Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, windows

I downloaded Ubuntu and put it on a usb drive to boot from it. I haven't tried booting from it yet since I don't know how I'll get back to Windows 10. Could someone explain how I will do that? Keep in mind, I have NOT booted to Ubuntu yet (if that changes anything).  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you shut down your PC when you're done using/testing your liveUSB Ubuntu, you remove your USB drive and turn your computer on as you would do every day.

It will boot on your installed OS normally.

Comment: Alright, so if I'm just running it from the USB temporarily, I can just take it out. But what if a actually install it alongside Windows, or is that the same thing?

Comment: Yes, if you're not installing it you just turn the PC off and remove the USB. In case you want to install ubuntu alongside windows it is a different procedure, sometimes a tricky one. You can find some really useful guides about how to partition your hard drive to make a dual boot system. Let me know if you can't find any and I'll help you out.

Comment: Okay, I'm definitely glad I asked then. I think I'm not going to install it, Just try it. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome! If you're satisfied with the answer, mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try it out and, when you finish everything, shut down your PC. Then turn on your PC and use it as normal. If you decide to install it, you may dual-boot it on your hard drive. Just try it.

Comment: All right, I'll try in a minute